# Copying a file with access locks, forcefully with python

Tags: python, excel-2003

I'm trying to copy an excel sheet with python, but I keep getting "access denied" error message. The file is closed and is not shared. It has macros though.

Is their anyway I can copy the file forcefully with python?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not have sufficient file permissions you will not be able to access the file. In that case you will have to execute your Python program as an user with sufficient permissions.

If on the other hand the file is locked using other means specific to Excel then I am not sure what exactly is the solution. You might have to work around the protection using other means which will require a fair amount of understanding of how Excel sheets are "locked". I don't know of any Python libraries that will do this for you.